# Have sed make substitute on string but SKIP first occurrence

Tags: sed

I have been through the [sed one liners](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/) but am still having trouble with my goal. I want to substitue matching strings on all but the first occurrence of a line. My exact usage would be:

```
 $ echo 'cd /Users/joeuser/bump bonding/initial trials' | sed <<MAGIC HAPPENS>
 cd /Users/joeuser/bump\ bonding/initial\ trials
```

The line replaced the space in `bump bonding` with the slash space `bump\ bonding` so that I can execute this line (since when the spaces aren't escaped I wouldn't be able to cd to it).

**Update**: I solved this by just using single quotes and outputting

```
 cd 'blah blah/thing/another space/'
```

and then using `source` to execute the command. But it didn't answer my question. I'm still curious though... how would you use `sed` to fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can avoid the problem with **`g`** and ***n***

Replace all of them, then undo the first one:

```
sed -e 's/ /\\ /g' -e 's/\\ / /1'
```

Here's another method which uses the `t` branch-if-substituted command:

```
sed ':a;s/\([^ ]* .*[^\\]\) \(.*\)/\1\\ \2/;ta'
```

which has the advantage of leaving existing backslash-space sequences in the input intact.

Comment: Your first answer looks to be the universal solution. With a little reading, the -e flag seems to be what I was really looking for.

Answer (score 18):

```
s/ /\\ /2g
```

The `2` specifies that the second one should apply, and the `g` specifies that all the rest should apply too. (This probably only works on GNU sed. According to the Open Group Base Specification, "[If both **g** and *n* are specified, the results are unspecified.](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)")

Comment: You are correct about the GNU sed. On my Mac it doesn't work. But this is the exact kind of elegant solution I was looking for.

Comment: @physicsmichael You can install GNU sed on a Mac with `brew install gsed`. After installation, you can type the command as `/usr/local/bin/gsed` instead of `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

use awk

```
$ echo cd 'blah blah/thing/another space/' | awk '{for(i=2;i<NF;i++) $i=$i"\\"}1'
cd blah\ blah/thing/another\ space/

$ echo 'cd /Users/joeuser/bump bonding/initial trials' | awk '{for(i=2;i<NF;i++) $i=$i"\\"}1'
cd /Users/joeuser/bump\ bonding/initial\ trials
```

Comment: explanation for 1 and \\ ?