# OSX sed newlines - why conversion of whitespace to newlines works, but newlines are not converted to spaces

Tags: macos, sed

sed on OSX has some quirks. This resource (http://nlfiedler.github.io/2010/12/05/newlines-in-sed-on-mac.html) contains information on how to convert whitespace into a newline:

```
 echo 'foo bar baz quux' | sed -e 's/ /\'$'\n/g'
```

OR (@ghoti's suggestion which does make it easier to read):

```
echo 'foo bar baz quux' |  sed -e $'s/ /\\\n/g'
```

However, when I try the reverse - converting newlines to whitespace, it doesn't work:

```
echo -e "foo\nbar" | sed -e 's/\'$'\n/ /g'
```

A more straightforward approach of just changing `\n` doesn't work either:

```
echo -e "foo\nbar" | sed -e 's/\n/ /g'
```

There's a related answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/307165/newlines-in-sed-on-mac-os-x, with a detailed answer by Spiff (right at the end of the page), however applying the same logic didn't resolve the problem.

Here's one way that does work on OSX (via http://www.benjiegillam.com/2011/09/using-sed-to-replace-newlines/):

```
 sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/ /g'
```

However, I am still curious why reversing the original approach doesn't work.

UPDATE: here's how to make it work with two lines (the solution is to use `N` to embed the newline characters):

```
echo -e "foo\nbar\n" | sed -e 'N;s/\n/ /g'
```

AN ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION (see full answer by @ghoti for detailed explanation):

```
echo -e "foo\nbar\n" | sed -n '1h;2,$H;${;x;s/\n/ /gp;}'
```

However, this solution appears to be a tiny bit slower than the one suggested in the question statement (note order of these commands matters, so it might make sense to try testing them in different orders):

```
time seq 10000 | sed -n '1h;2,$H;${;x;s/\n/ /gp;}' > /dev/null

time seq 10000 | sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/ /g' > /dev/null
```

Comment: Try your updated solution with three lines of input. And check out my answer below. :)

Comment: Also, in case you didn't see this, your very first example, `'s/ /\'$'\n/g'`, is actually relying on shell expansion. (Check the QUOTING section of your friendly neighbourhood bash man page.) It'll work in bash and some other shells, but it's not universal (or POSIX). You might make it clearer or easier to read by just using the same quoting style for the whole expression: `sed -e $'s/ /\\\n/g'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question appears to be "why doesn't the reverse of the original approach [of converting spaces to newlines] work?".

In sed, the newline is more of a record separator than part of the line. Consider that `$`, the null at the end of the pattern space, comes after the last character of the line, and is not a newline of every line.

Sed commands that utilize newlines, like `H` and `N` and even `s`, do so outside the scope of newline-as-record-separator.  The records you're substituting are between the newlines.

In order to substitute a newline, then, you need to get it INSIDE the pattern space, using `N`, `H`, etc.

So here's an option.

```
printf 'foo\nbar\nbaz\n' | sed -n '1h;2,$H;${;x;s/\n/ /gp;}'
```

The idea is that we'll append all our lines to the hold buffer, then at the end of the file, move the hold buffer back to the pattern space for substitution, and replace the newlines with spaces all at once.

The `1h;2,$H` construction avoids a blank at the beginning of your output, caused by the newline that is appended before each line of data with `H`.

Comment: Thank you! It works, but I wonder if the `${}` is going to put any extra strain on performance?

Comment: I suspect that if there's a performance impact, it will be on very large files, since with this solution sed needs to store ALL your input data in memory (the hold buffer) until it reaches the end of the file. If you want something more streamlined, perhaps `awk '{printf("%s ",$0)}'` would be a better option, or `tr '\n' ' '` if that's sufficient for your needs. But this is solutioning again. The answer to your question is the part above, about newlines-as-delimiters rather than as part of the string.

Answer (score 1):

The GNU manual page for `sed` includes:

> **REGULAR EXPRESSIONS**
>
> POSIX.2  BREs  should  be supported, but they aren't completely because of performance problems.  The `\n` sequence in a regular expression matches the newline character, and  similarly for `\a`, `\t`, and other sequences.

The Mac OS X manual page for `sed` includes:

> **Sed Regular Expressions**
>
> The regular expressions used in `sed`, by default, are basic regular expressions (BREs, see re_format(7) for more information), but extended (modern) regular expressions can be used instead if the `-E` flag is given.  In addition, `sed` has the following two additions to regular expressions:
>
> 1. In a context address, any character other than a backslash (`\`) or newline character may be used to delimit the regular expression.  Also, putting a backslash character before the delimiting character causes the character to be treated literally. For example, in the context address `\xabc\xdefx`, the RE delimiter is an `x` and the second `x` stands for itself, so that the regular expression is `abcxdef`.
> 2. The escape sequence `\n` matches a newline character embedded in the pattern space.  You cannot, however, use a literal newline character in an address or in the substitute command.

What these don't say, but what seems to be the case, is that in the `s/regex/new/` command, the `regex` section is a regular expression, but the `new` section is not.  In the replacement material, you have to use `\` followed by a newline to embed a newline.  In the search material (`regex`), you can use `\n`.

Note also that `sed` works on lines.  By default, the newline at the end of the pattern space is pretty much unmatchable except with the regex metacharacter `$`; you can't simply remove that newline by matching it.  You can, however, end up with multiple lines in the pattern space, and then you can match embedded newlines with the `\n` pattern.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I tried at first and it didn't work. `sed -e 's/\n/ /g'` The working code in the question statement also contains `\n` in the search material, yet that part strangely works (when it is preceded by explicit reading of the file).

Comment: There's an issue that `sed` is line based, and the last newline "doesn't count".  You can't just remove a newline from the end of a line; you can remove a newline embedded because you've been playing with commands that embed newlines (`N` and `H` for example).

Comment: It looks like I've accidentally been quoting the GNU `sed` manual, too.  My mistake.  And I wish I understood how it is going wrong — the manual is tucked massively out of the way (`~/oss/share/man/man1/sed.1`), but even with MANPATH unset, `man` is managing to find it.  Grrr!  Fortunately, I don't think my comments about the manual are inaccurate — just what I'm quoting isn't what I thought I was quoting.  When I've worked out how to brainwash `man`, I'll update the information.

Comment: For anyone following along, the Mac OS X `man` command has a configuration file in `/private/etc/man.conf` and one of the entries there says: _`# NOAUTOPATH keeps man from automatically adding directories that look like manual page directories to the path.`_  I didn't (and still don't) have that enabled, so `man` managed to find some directories that contained man-pages and looked in those.  I got to the Mac OS X version using `man -M /usr/share/man sed`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, thanks for that. So much of OSX is un- or obscurely documented. Just have to figure out how to record atoms of wisdom like this, because they're so easily forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of alternatives, that I tend to fall back on when stymied by OSX `sed` peculiarities, are `tr` and `perl`.

```
echo -e "foo\nbar" | tr '\n' ' '
foo bar

echo -e "foo\nbar" | perl -pe 's/\n/ /'
foo bar
```

Comment: Thanks, tr is very handy. For this question I'm really curious about OSX's sed behaviour, but your answer can help someone who's looking for any solution.

Comment: @ghoti I agree, but it is pertinent and constructive - just a bit awkward to express in a comment :-)