# Replace starting from the second column

Tags: unix, sed, replace, dataset

Well, I have the following file:

```
12721   2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2
12722   2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2
12734   2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2
12753   2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2
12756   2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2
```

I need to remove the spaces starting from the second column, so that my file looks like this:

```
12721 222112121112211212112
12722 222112121112211212112
12734 222112121112211212112
12753 222112121112211212112
12756 222112121112211212112
```

I tried this command to replace:

```
sed '1,$s/ //g' snpdata > snpdata1
```

it did not work and I got it:

```
12721222112121112211212112
12722222112121112211212112
12734222112121112211212112
12753222112121112211212112
12756222112121112211212112
```

any suggestions to replace starting from the second column?

Note: my original dataset has thousands of columns and rows.

Comment: you seems to be changed you expected output now :) let me tweak my code too now.

Comment: If you have access to a GNU sed, you may use `sed 's/[[:space:]]//2g'` (or `sed -r 's/[[:space:]]+//2g'`)

Comment: Thank u Ravinder, and sorry for mistake

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Have sed make substitute on string but SKIP first occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166007/have-sed-make-substitute-on-string-but-skip-first-occurrence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP changed expected output now, so tweaked code a bit this should help OP for latest expected output.

```
awk '{val=$1;$1="";gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"");print val,$0}'  Input_file
```

---

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk '{val=substr($0,5);gsub(/ +/,"",val);print substr($0,1,4), val;val=""}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
 sed 's/ //g;s/\([0-9]\{5\}\)\([0-9]\+\)/\1 \2/' file
```

where the first command removes all spaces and the second command groups the digits

Comment: Sorry, I edit my question. Please, Can you get your program right?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\([^ ]\)  */\1\n/1;s/ //g;s/\n/ /' file
```

Replace the first set of spaces following a column, by a newline. Remove all other spaces. Replace the newline by a space.