# Using Grep to pull lines while omitting repetitive string

Tags: string, grep, cpu-word, bsd

My input file is

```
cat random.txt

hello my name is hello
```

When I use `egrep '^hello|hello$ random.txt`

results are 
`hello my name is hello`

How would I modify the command to instead output something like this

```
hello my name is
```

or

```
my name is hello
```

basically removing the same word if it starts at the beginning or end of the line
if both words were to be on the same line?

Comment: You need more examples of what you want.  Your `grep` command looks for `hello` at the beginning or end of a line, but will print the whole line.  But you apparently want some processing after that, or some indication whether the "hello at beginning" or "hello at end" was triggered.  What if a line says `hello my name is Bob and I say hello whenever anybody says hello to me, hello"  What do you want the output to be?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine it with `awk` like this:

```
egrep '^hello|hello$' random.txt | awk '{$1=""; print $0}'
```

That means, the results from `egrep` are sent to `awk`. `awk` splits each word, resets the first word represented by `$1` to empty string and prints out rest of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use `grep`? You can achieve this effect with `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/hello/PLACEHOLDER/g' -e 's/PLACEHOLDER/hello/1' -e 's/PLACEHOLDER//1' random.txt
```

Which returns:

```
hello my name is
```

To clarify what we did:

- First we replace all matches of "hello" with "PLACEHOLDER"
- Then we replace the first match of "PLACEHOLDER" with hello
- Finally we replace the remaing matches of "PLACEHOLDER" with an empty string

This solution is based in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2166468/2203828) for a question regarding sed.